# numpy.argpartition documentation not clear enough

Tags: python, numpy

I've tried to understand the `numpy.argpartition` by reading its documentation, but I still get confused.
In [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html), it is said that

> it returns an array of indices that index the data along the given axis in partitioned order.

What I didn't get in this sentence is "**in partitioned order**".
Also when I used `np.argpartition` with an example, I didn't get anything logical (for me).

```
>>> a = np.array([352, 538, 215, 400, 631, 498, 586, 731])
>>> np.argpartition(a, 2)
array([2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> np.argpartition(a, 3)
array([2, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7])
```

What I expected is an array with the indexes of the sorted values of the array a.

Can anyone explain/clarify how `np.argpartition` works?

Comment: It might be easier to make sense of the `np.partition(a, 2)` output.  You didn't ask for `argsort`.  `partition` is a partial sort, not a complete one.

Comment: I read the documentation of `numpy.partition` and it was easy to be understood. However I could not figure out how `numpy.argpartition` works

Comment: `a[argpartion(a,n)]` should produce the same thing as `partition`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [163]: np.argpartition(a, 3)                                                                              
Out[163]: array([2, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7])
In [164]: a[_]                                                                                               
Out[164]: array([215, 352, 400, 498, 538, 631, 586, 731])
In [165]: np.partition(a,3)                                                                                  
Out[165]: array([215, 352, 400, 498, 538, 631, 586, 731])
```

In both 164 and 165, everything to the left of 400 is smaller, everything to right is larger.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out now. The output of `numpy.argpartition (a, 3)` is an array that contains the indexes of the elements of a in a sorted way (array([2, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 7]) means that: in the sorted version of a, the element of a whose index is 2 will be the first, then the element whose index is 0 will be the second and so on, till we reach the 4 position in a. And by this we will have the smaller values before 400 and the bigger values after it.). Am I right?

Comment: In other words: `numpy.argpartition(a, 3)` will take the element whose index is 3 from the array a, and return an array that contains *the indexes of the elements from a that are smaller than a[3], a[3], then the elements from a that are greater than a[3].* I think that this is a simpler version of what I said in my previous comment.